# Vue.component alternative in Vue 3

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-mix

I'm using Vue with Laravel Mix. In Vue version 2, I was able to do this:

```
1. resources/js/app.js:

import Vue from 'vue';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
Vue.component('my-component', MyComponent);
```

---

```
2. resources/js/MyComponent.vue:

<template>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "MyComponent",
    props: ['message']
}
</script>
```

As [this Vue 2 document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration) instructed. I know it was not the best practice, but it was the only approach that I have to conveniently pass data from Laravel's `Blade template` to the component, such as below:

```
3. anyview.blade.php:
<my-component :message='message' id='app'></my-component>
<script src='public/js/app.js'><script> //include compiled resources/js/app.js
<script>
    let app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data() {
            return {
                message: 'Hello World';
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

In real case, 'Hello World' would be replaced with something like:

```
message: {{$myMessaGe}}
```

But since [Vue 3](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#global-registration), `Vue.component` is no longer a thing because `Vue` object is not a default export.

This work flow (1-2-3) has been seamlessly fine, so returning to Vue2 is the last unhappy choice :(

---

I have tried to work around, just changing `Vue.component` with the new `createApp`:

```
4. resources/js/app.js:

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
createApp({
    components: {
        MyComponent,
    }
}).mount('#app');
```

But instead of adding `MyComponent` to current instance, it just creates a new one as depicted below - meaning that the prop `message` can't be passed through.

[image]

---

My question is: **Is there any alternative API or workaround to compensate the loss of `Vue.component()`**?

Answer (score 4):

I have only worked with Vue3 so far but what I understand from the documentation is that the components in Vue3 are not that different from components in Vue2.

Try this solution:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

const app = createApp({});

app
   .component('MyComponent', MyComponent)
   .mount('#app');
```

You can find more about this in the [Vue3 docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#global-registration).

Comment: It just creates another instance as I depicted in (4). Which mean prop value can't be passed through

Comment: What is you frontpage? And is MyComponent part of your frontpage?
I have a SPA with 'App.vue' as my frontpage which only consists of the HTML-structure and all the components but no content. This works for me: import {createApp} from "vue"; import App from "./App.vue"; import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue"; createApp(App).component("MyComponent", MyComponent).mount("#app");

Comment: My front page is rendered by PHP and I was only intended to use Vue as a component, not for an entire SPA, and I want to pass data from PHP view to the component via props. If I understand correctly, you are moving all component to SFC, which definitely works, if so, how can you passs PHP `myMessage` to Vue?

Comment: And yes, HTML structures do get rendered, but since props is not passed, there is no content

Comment: did you find a solution to this please?